# How to connect JIRA with Power BI to fetch project and sprint details?

Tags: jira, powerbi, business-intelligence, jira-rest-api

I am connecting JIRA with Power BI by using the Power BI Content packs developed for JIRA. Once I am able to connect, I wish to see all the data related to JIRA such as Sprints, Stories, Assignee and Projects

But I am unable to see the information while I see one example in my organisation that were able to connect Sprint information with the Power BI

Can you let me know what I have been doing wrong that doesn't allow me to see key information present in my company's JIRA database?

Comment: Would it be easier to ask how the other people in your organisation has done it?

Comment: I think it may be possible to add the sprint field by adding the "fields" rest API parameter to the dataset connection.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use a custom SQL, the pack may include only basic about issues.